# контейнер в founation с 8 колонками

Tags: html, css, foundation

что-то подобное как в колонках offset, только сделать в контейнер слева и справа по 2 колонки. Чтобы таким образом у нас получился 8-колоночный контейнер

Answer (score 1):

Заходим в settings.scss
$grid-columns: 8;
$grid-container: Нужная ширина